Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 80 , Thingsboard
I am using thingsboard cloud and wanted to import a dashboard text
But I am getting error as Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 80 in my thingsboard.Anyone has any idea on how to resolve this issue
I tried to import it after downlaoding the dashboard

It looks like the dashboard file you're trying to import is either corrupted or improperly encoded. To resolve this make sure the dashboard file is complete and not truncated.
Try opening the file in a text editor and check for any invalid characters or formatting issues.
If possible, re-export the dashboard from ThingsBoard and try importing again.
Make sure the file is in the correct format (usually .json) and encoded as UTF-8.
